# JIRA filter for tickets handled by a person

Tags: project-management, jira

How can I create a filter in JIRA if I want to know what all tickets a particular person has worked on?

There can be cases where the ticket was not actually assigned to a person or resolved by him, however still he has worked on it. This can be tracked by looking at his comments inside that JIRA. I want to get all such tickets in which a particular person has involvement (comments given, assigned to, Resolved by, Fixed by, etc all cases). How can I create such a filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with the standard JQL in JIRA. You'd have to write something custom to make it work.

That said, there is an easy way to enable something like this, but it will only work with tickets going forward, not with any comments or participation already in place.

The [JIRA Toolkit Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.toolkit) will give you a *Participants* field which you can add as a custom field to every type and in a global context (or with any other config you chose). The participant field will track anyone who comments on a ticket, raises a ticket, or is the CURRENT assignee.  Unfortunately, it does not keep a history of all assignees. This can be remedied by making comments required for actions that involve reassignment (Assign to, resolve, etc).

The Participant field can then be queried.

Comment: Yes, I'd use the Participants field

Comment: Thanks for the very useful tip Jason.. I can use this at least for future tickets.